# nested if else condition

Tags: python, if-statement

Hi I have a question regarding the following nested condition (python):

```
If (A meet B):
     condition 1;
     If(A meet B):
          condition2;
```

does it mean that if A meet B perform condition 1, and if A meet B again, perform condition 2?

Comment: Well, yes it does - Python's indenting specifies that the second if statement is only executed if the first  `A meets B` is truthy. You can test this yourself by making your code runnaable and putting print statements where the two condition lines are.

Comment: Yes it would do that but it would be pointless unless A or B changes in condition 1. There are definitely better ways to write this too but would need to see a code example

Comment: Yes, that's the case but the wording is pretty weird, in python every indentation of the if means you are under the previously given condition.

Comment: Welcome. If you use Python pay attention to those deatils: `If` is not a valid name(you use `if` instead), In Python `;`  is not necesery(At least in this case, `;` is useful in other cases). Next time check that your code run. since you have a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's how it works.
Here is an example:

**program:**

```
a = 10
b = 10
if a == b:
    print("a is equals to b")
    if a == b:
        print("a is again equals to b")
```

**output:**

```
a is equals to b
a is again equals to b
```

Answer (score 0):

The first *if* loop is applied for every condition you set, so both outputs will show you Condition1 and Condition2. Here is a simple example to understand it:

```
x = 2
if x == 2:
    print("hello")
    if x == 2:
        print("goodbye")
```

> Output: hello goodbye

But if the first *if* loop modifies the initial condition, the second *if* loop would not work:

```
x = 2
if x == 2:
    x += 1
    if x == 2:
        x -= 4
print(x)
```

> Output: x = 3